# Using COUNT with a HAVING Clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

We are having some trouble figuring out why we can't COUNT while using the HAVING clause at the end of our statement.

This statement returns results:

```
SELECT lid, cid, title, url, description, date, hits, downloadratingsummary, totalvotes, totalcomments, filesize, version, homepage, ns_compat, ns_des_img, ( (2.0 * (MATCH(title) AGAINST ('fsx concorde' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) + (1.0 * (MATCH(description) AGAINST ('fsx concorde' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) + (0.5 * (MATCH(url) AGAINST ('fsx concorde' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) ) AS relevance FROM nuke_downloads_downloads WHERE ( MATCH(title,description,url) AGAINST ('fsx concorde' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) HAVING relevance > 3.0 ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

This statement returns nothing

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num, lid, cid, title, url, description, date, hits, downloadratingsummary, totalvotes, totalcomments, filesize, version, homepage, ns_compat, ns_des_img, ( (2.0 * (MATCH(title) AGAINST ('fsx concorde' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) + (1.0 * (MATCH(description) AGAINST ('fsx concorde' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) + (0.5 * (MATCH(url) AGAINST ('fsx concorde' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) ) AS relevance FROM nuke_downloads_downloads WHERE ( MATCH(title,description,url) AGAINST ('fsx concorde' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) HAVING relevance > 3.0 ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Are we missing anything here?

Your help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want to count?

Comment: We want to count the number of rows returned by the SQL command.  The COUNT function works fine without the HAVING command at the end of the query.

Comment: Can't you do at the application (that receives the results)? From what I remember the usual PHP modules that send queries to MySQL have this feature already. Unless you want just a number, only the COUNT and not the results.

Comment: I can't remember how `HAVING` works, but don't you need to use `GROUP BY` in order to count the right thing?

Comment: Application level in PHP (mysql_num_rows) seems much slower (lots of CPU usage by PHP) and we would have to perform the query twice as we are also limiting the results for pagination of the results returned.  Unless we can combine the limits in the SQL statement and then also perform a row count on all "available" results in one query?

Comment: Although it's not documented, you can actually use the HAVING without the GROUP BY syntax.  Not standard, but it does work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only the count of rows that the first query would return, you can encapulate the query into a derived table.

You can skip all the columns except the `relevance` from the `SELECT` list and the `ORDER BY`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  ( SELECT ( (2.0 * (MATCH ... ) AS relevance 
    FROM ...                                     -- unchanged
    WHERE ...                                    -- unchanged
    HAVING relevance > 3.0
                                                 -- ORDER BY removed    
  ) AS t ;
```